# Backlight screen flickering on a Sony Vaio VPCYB15AL

Tags: 11.10, graphics, ati, vaio

I've just installed Ubuntu 11.10, and everything went just now when the computer got into suspension, when it got back the screen started flickering, specially on the dashboard, it trends to disappear when i turn down the backlight, at first it was fixed by rebooting the system and now, every time that I start Ubuntu as soon as the desktod loads it starts flickering again, please help!

I have a  Sony VAIO VPCYB15AL AMD Dual Core E350 with an ATI HD 6310.

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same problem, it seemed to be solved when installing the proprietary driver, on my system it works, but I get a logo on the screen right down: AMD not supported hardware. The tips about removing this logo with a script as can be found on the Internet does not work in this case. Afterwards I removed the proprietary driver and now I startup using Unity-2D which does not have this problem (and quicker startup, hardly any difference with 3D and longer battery life, less fan noice).
Best 
RoK